# javax.persistence in java-6-openjdk

Tags: maven-2, hudson, spring-roo, java

I am trying to perform the build of a Spring Roo project (= Spring MVC + aspectj + hibernate) on my hudson integration server.

The project is configured tu use

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>com.springsource.javax.persistence</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The build with my local maven works fine, but the environment on the server seems to inject some other version of `javax.persistence` which leads to these errors:

```
[ERROR] The method createQuery(String) in the type EntityManager is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class<Long>)
[ERROR] The method createQuery(String) in the type EntityManager is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class<Folder>)
```

The build is ran with maven and it's configuration is:

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-4)
Java version: 1.6.0_18
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.32-5-amd64" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

edit: I wasn't using the same version of roo locally and on the server :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using JPA2 in your project?

JPA2 is part of Java EE 6, and from what I see, you're using [this](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) method:

```
<T> TypedQuery<T> createQuery(java.lang.String qlString, java.lang.Class<T> resultClass)
```

This method doesn't exist in JPA1 (Java EE 5), as you can see by examining [EntityManager](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) where only

```
Query createQuery(String qlString)
```

exists.

All of this means that Hudson is using `javax.persistence` for JPA1. I haven't used Hudson, so you will have to find out if you can make it use `javax.persistence` for JPA2.

Comment: Good analysis (+1). But I don't think the problem lies with hudson. I think the maven dependency is wrong

Comment: I found my problem ! 

Roo actually generate code for you. On my local machine I used Roo 1.0.1 which generates JPA1 code and adds a persistence v1 dependency.

But on the server I installed roo 1.1 which generated JPA2 code, and tried to compile based on my commited pom.xml ..

Answer (score 0):

What's strange is that it works locally.

You have a dependency to JPA 1, but use methods of JPA 2 (`createQuery(query, class)`).

Check your local classpath.